# Mysql for every n-th update to do a special update

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to do something like this with mysql?

Imagine I've update query, that runs every time user gives successful answer. Now I'd like to count updates and give +1 bonus point every fourth time...

I could just count rows and divide them by 4, but that would give me non spendable bonus points, because for every update it will get recalculated...

Is there any mysql solution to my problem?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: @Femaref What do you mean? I want user to receive bonus point for every 4 th correct answer.

Comment: I think you'll end up doing some sort of 'row# % 4 = 0'. You could use a trigger if you were feeling crafty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may use trigger and calculate additional bonuses when user gives successful answer.

Here is working example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS answer;

CREATE TABLE answer
(
  id int not null auto_increment,
  bonus int not null,
  primary key(id)
);

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER lucky_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON answer
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF MOD((SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'answer'), 4) = 0 THEN
      SET NEW.bonus = NEW.bonus + 1;
  END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO answer(bonus) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO answer(bonus) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO answer(bonus) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO answer(bonus) VALUES(1);

SELECT id, bonus FROM answer;
```

Will give you next output:

```
+----+-------+
| id | bonus |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     1 |
|  2 |     1 |
|  3 |     1 |
|  4 |     2 |
+----+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```